# warn and provide the number of files that will be affected by rsync command

Tags: bash, shell-script, rsync

My `rsync`'s `--dry-run` output is:

```
% rsync --dry-run -avi --delete-after /home/blueray/Documents/rsync-test/src /home/blueray/Documents/rsync-test/dest
building file list ... done
.d..t...... src/
>f.st...... src/empty-asciidoc-document 3.adoc
>f+++++++++ src/empty-asciidoc-document 4.adoc
>f+++++++++ src/empty-asciidoc-document-renamed.adoc
*deleting   src/empty-asciidoc-document.adoc
*deleting   src/empty-asciidoc-document 2.adoc

sent 254 bytes  received 27 bytes  562.00 bytes/sec
total size is 16  speedup is 0.06 (DRY RUN)
```

I am looking for output like the following:

```
building file list ... done
.d..t...... src/
>f.st...... src/empty-asciidoc-document 3.adoc
>f+++++++++ src/empty-asciidoc-document 4.adoc
>f+++++++++ src/empty-asciidoc-document-renamed.adoc
*deleting   src/empty-asciidoc-document.adoc
*deleting   src/empty-asciidoc-document 2.adoc

sent 254 bytes  received 27 bytes  562.00 bytes/sec
total size is 16  speedup is 0.06 (DRY RUN)

Warning: n files will be affected, do you want to continue?
```

The script I came up with so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash

affected_files=$(rsync --dry-run -avi --delete-after /home/blueray/Documents/rsync-test/src /home/blueray/Documents/rsync-test/dest)
echo $affected_files

number_of_affected_files=$(echo $affected_files | grep src | wc -l)

echo "Warning: ${number_of_affected_files} files will be affected, do you want to continue?"

while true; do
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) rsync -avi --delete-after /home/blueray/Documents/rsync-test/src /home/blueray/Documents/rsync-test/dest; break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) read -p "Please answer yes or no: " yn;;
    esac
done
```

However, it has a few issues. `$affected_files` does not maintain line breaks. So, the script is not working. Moreover, I am not sure whether `$affected_files | grep src | wc -l` giving an actual number of affected files or not.

What can I do?

Comment: You need to double quote your variables in order to see line breaks. This is true for output and also for line counting. Try `echo "$affected_files"` in both cases.

Comment: Also note that, depending on the number of files, the list might be too long. You might want to use `tee` to print the output **and** save it to a file. Then you'd do your counting on the file saved by `tee`.

Comment: Consider using the `--stats` option in the dry run which prints the "Number of files" among other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here, the script I am currently using is:

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync -ab --dry-run --stats --human-readable --inplace --debug=NONE --log-file=rsync.log --backup-dir=rsync_bak.$(date +"%d-%m-%y_%I-%M-%S%P") --log-file-format='%t %f %o %M' --delete-after /home/blueray/Documents/rsync-testsrc /home/blueray/Documents/rsync-testdest | sed -e '1d;5,12d;14,17d'

echo -e "\nDo you want to continue?"

while true; do
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) rsync -ab --human-readable --inplace --info=PROGRESS2,BACKUP,DEL --debug=NONE --log-file=/home/blueray/Documents/rsync-testdest/rsync.log --backup-dir=rsync_bak.$(date +"%d-%m-%y_%I-%M-%S%P") --log-file-format='%t %f %o %M' --delete-after /home/blueray/Documents/rsync-testsrc /home/blueray/Documents/rsync-testdest; break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) read -p "Please answer yes or no: " yn;;
    esac
done
```